# error while installing RESTful Web Services and HAL module

Tags: 8

I'm trying to install RESTful Web Services and HAL Module in Drupal 8 core , but it is showing the following error.

> ERROR: The always_populate_raw_post_data PHP setting should be set to -1 in PHP version 5.6. Please check the PHP manual for information on how to correct this. (Currently using always_populate_raw_post_data PHP setting version Not set to -1.)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says you should put this in php.ini.

```
always_populate_raw_post_data=-1
```

If you don't have access to the PHP configuration, this is also possible in .htaccess.

```
php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
```

This only works if the web server admin allows to override options in .htaccess.